# How to test if defined and return value or some default value

Tags: perl

In my code, I often write things like this:

```
my $a = defined $scalar ? $scalar : $default_value;
```

or

```
my $b = exists $hash{$_} ? $hash{$_} : $default_value;
```

Sometimes the hash is quite deep and the code is not very readable. Is there a more concise way to do the above assignments?

Comment: Obligatory comment about never using `$a` and `$b` for real because of their special nature with respect to `sort`. We now return to our regularly-scheduled programming...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming you're using Perl 5.10 and above, you can use the `//` operator.

```
my $a = defined $x ? $x : $default;  # clunky way
my $a = $x // $default;              # nice way
```

Similarly you can do

```
my $b = defined $hash{$_} ? $hash{$_} : $default;  # clunky
my $b = $hash{$_} // $default;                     # nice
```

Note that in my example above I'm checking `defined $hash{$_}`, not `exists $hash{$_}` like you had.  There's no shorthand for existence like there is for definedness.

Finally, you have the `//=` operator, so you can do;

```
$a = $x unless defined $a;  # clunky
$a //= $x;                  # nice
```

This is analogous to the `||=` which does the same for truth:

```
$a = $x unless $x;  # Checks for truth, not definedness.
$a ||= $x;
```